# Interpreting results from emmeans comparison

Tags: r, glm, emmeans

I have a glm model with two fixed effects, Treatment and Date, to estimate Temperature from data collected in a time series. Within Treatment there are three different categories: Fucus, Terrycloth or Control, and temperature is measured beneath those canopies. The model is created like so `mod1 <- glm(Temp ~ Treatment * Date, data = aveTerry.df )`

I am trying to tell if Terrycloth has a similar effect as Fucus canopy (i.e. replicates it).

I found the `emmeans` package and believe it could help me compare between these levels within treatment by using my model, and have used it as so to find the estimated marginal means `terry.emmeans <- emmeans(modAllTerry, poly ~ Treatment | Date)` and plotted the comparisons via `plot(terry.emmeans.average, comparison = TRUE) +theme_bw()`

Giving me this output linked here.

[image: emmeans output plot]

I am looking for some help understanding what this graphical output is, especially **what exactly are the comparisons** (which are shown by the red arrows). I somewhat understand the that blue boxes are the confidence intervals for the mean value of temperature for each treatment on one day (based on model), but am wondering how is the comparison made? **And why do some days only have a one sided arrow**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation for `plot.emmGrid`, the comparison arrows are created in such a way that two arrows are disjoint if and only if their respective means are significantly different at the stated level.

The lowest mean in the set has only a right-pointing arrow because that mean will not be compared with anything smaller, obviating the need for a left-pointing arrow. For similar reasons, the highest mean has only a left-pointing arrow. These arrows do not define intervals; their only purpose is depicting comparisons.

In situations where the SEs of pairwise comparisons vary widely, it may not be possible to construct comparison arrows. If that happens, an error message is displayed.

Confidence intervals are available as well, but those CIs should not be used for comparing means.

More information and examples may be found via `vignette("comparisons", "emmeans")`. Also, details of how the arrows are actually constructed are given in `vignette("xplanations", "emmeans")`

Comment: Hmmm. Looking at the graph, I see I have more work to do. For each date, we should have only one dot with two arrows, one with only a left arrow, and one with only a right arrow.

Comment: I have finally addressed this in emmeans version >= 1.5.1.1 (on github if not yet on CRAN)