# Interpretating `emmean` values with aligned-ranks transform anova (ART)

Tags: r, median, emmeans

I am working with `ARTool` to analyze differences between factors in non-parametric data. I am struggling to understand the `emmean` values that provided (what are the units?). How should they be interpreted? Are they the best estimate of central tendency to compare groups that is similar to the algorithm used in the analysis? I am trying to visualize differences between groups to understand the output.

Here is an example using `iris`:

```
data(iris)
iris.art<-art(Sepal.Length~Species, data=iris)
emmeans(artlm(iris.art, "Species"), ~Species)
#Species    emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
#setosa       29.6 3.65 147     22.4     36.9
#versicolor   82.7 3.65 147     75.4     89.9
#virginica   114.2 3.65 147    107.0    121.4

#Confidence level used: 0.95

with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, mean))
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#5.006      5.936      6.588
with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, median))
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#5.0        5.9        6.5
```

I have consulted:
[Interpreting results from emmeans comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713439/interpreting-results-from-emmeans-comparison)
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html

EDIT/UPDATE: Thanks to the very helpful comment, it does appear that `emmeans` is providing the average of ranks. Here is an example with a smaller subset of the `iris` data.

```
subset<-iris[c(1:3, 51:53, 101:103),c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]

with(subset, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, mean))
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#4.900000   6.766667   6.400000 

#run ART
iris.art<-art(Sepal.Length~Species, data=subset)

#extract ranks from ART
ranks_art<-iris.art$aligned.ranks
names(ranks_art)<-"ranks_art"
subset$ranks<-as.vector(t((iris.art$aligned.ranks)))
subset[order(subset$Sepal.Length),]
#       Sepal.Length  Species ranks
#3            4.7     setosa     1
#2            4.9     setosa     2
#1            5.1     setosa     3
#102          5.8  virginica     4
#101          6.3  virginica     5
#52           6.4 versicolor     6
#53           6.9 versicolor     7
#51           7.0 versicolor     8
#103          7.1  virginica     9


with(subset, tapply(ranks, Species, mean))
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#2          7          6 

emmeans(artlm(iris.art, "Species"), ~Species)
#Species    emmean SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#setosa          2  1  6   -0.447     4.45
#versicolor      7  1  6    4.553     9.45
#virginica       6  1  6    3.553     8.45
#
#Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: emmeans just works with predictions from the model. So the question isn't what emmeans() is estimating, but what is being predicted by iris.art, and what does artlm() do? If I had to guess (and this really is jus a wild guess) I'd say that the emmeans results are some kind of average of the *ranks* of the sepal lengths.

Comment: @Russ Lenth Thanks! I ran a couple of tests with the dummy dataset and it does appear to be providing the average of the ranks.